# "ERROR: Domain starts with dot in string" while sending Jenkins email with email extension plugin

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I have Email Extension Plugin 2.57.2 installed. Emails were working fine till I updated the plugin to 2.58. After errors I have downgraded it to 2.57.2 but that did not help. I don't know what version I had to begin with. Any ideas? I don't have a `.` in the domain `somedomain` anywhere in settings or configuration.

```
00:05:21.000 Email was triggered for: Success
00:05:21.001 Sending email for trigger: Success
00:05:21.238 ERROR: Could not send email as a part of the post-build publishers.
00:05:21.239 javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Domain starts with dot in string ``abc@.somedomain.com''
00:05:21.239    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:1247)
00:05:21.239    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:1091)
00:05:21.239    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parseHeader(InternetAddress.java:658)
00:05:21.239    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:701)
00:05:21.239    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getRecipients(MimeMessage.java:534)
00:05:21.239    at javax.mail.Message.getAllRecipients(Message.java:305)
00:05:21.239    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAllRecipients(MimeMessage.java:549)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.sendMail(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:447)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher._perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:435)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.perform(ExtendedEmailPublisher.java:343)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:730)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:676)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:196)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1782)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
00:05:21.239    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
00:05:21.239 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: are you using a Jenkinsfile? could you post it?

Comment: Its not a Jenkinsfile can tell from the backtrace its a FreeStyleBuild

Comment: @DavidvanLaatum Yes it is a free style build.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is from the java mail api. Either a user has an invalid email configured, the job has an invalid email configured, or the SCM has an invalid email (or the global default domain starts with a dot).

I have made no recent changes to the plugin that would cause this to start happening so probably not related to the upgrade.